# iTunes - Playlist to MP3s, with track numbers

Tags: itunes

I listen to podcasts exclusively in my car, creating a playlist in iTunes, ordering by release date, and then burning to disc ensures I listen to them all in the correct order. Sadly, my new car doesn't have a CD player (just 2 SD slots and an iPod connector) so I cannot do this any more.

Anyway, you can create an MP3 folder by dragging the playlist to your desktop in Windows, but unfortunately the tracks are all in alphabetical order... I guess what I'm basically asking is **can you create a folder so it numbers the tracks (including the tag track title) 01, 02, 03 etc like it does an MP3 CD**?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1476480?start=0&tstart=0) help ?

Comment: Do you have to use iTunes?  There is much better software out there with features like this built-in.  I don't believe this is possible in iTunes.

Comment: do you insist on avoiding third party softwares?

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't mind using third party software at all for the conversion but honestly have no intention of switching away from iTunes - it'd be a real pain since between us we have an iPhone, two iPods and an iPad, all of which pretty much require iTunes

Comment: Since your care has an iPod connector and lots of iPods, why not just use your iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am making a few assumptions:

1. You are ready to use third-party software
2. Your tracks already have track numbers in their ID3 tags

In that case,

1. Export the tracks to folder as usual
2. Get musicbrainz picard.
3. Import the tracks into it.
4. Go to settings and and configure rename format to rename tracks with track number ahead of name(they have pretty clear help right there)
5. Update track info from internet if you wish to(Using "Scan" and "Lookup" options)
6. Make sure "Rename files" is ticked (in "Options" or "Tools")
7. Click "Save".

That should rename all the files.

**EDIT**

well...this might sound ridiculous....but, burn a CD and rip it again....see if it works that way.

try to burn it via image recorder. will save you a lot CDs..
I am sure if iTunes supports image recorder though..

Comment: Thank you, this is a good suggestion but unfortunately I need it to exactly match the order I have it in iTunes (then rename the track and set the track title tag accordingly) - I think because they're podcasts this may mean things such as musicbrainz won't work as well either :(

Comment: how did you maintain the ORDER after copying the files to a folder in the past.

and if they are mp3 files, picard can handle them.

Comment: when you burn to a CD from iTunes it generates the tags etc for you, but simply copying the files to a folder it doesn't do that :(

Comment: well...this might sound ridiculous....but, burn a CD and rip it again....see if it works that way.

Comment: @Nick: I have updated the answer. Kindly mark is as accepted if you are satisfied..

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be a pain, but if you aren't working with too many tracks, you might try adding "0# -" before the name of the track (i.e. "01 - track 1"). This would make it sort in whatever order you like.

However, if you have too many tracks, this is not feasible.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good suggestion, but unfortunately I need to change the tag of each track title too, so yup, could take a good while every time I put new podcasts on :(